# UICollectionView with buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am using a `UICollectionView` and I am thinking how to add buttons for each collection view cell and I don't want all buttons to do the same actions. I need to change buttons actions. I don't know how to do that.

```
import UIKit

class FirstARViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var imagescv = ["cv1","cv2","cv3","cv4","cv5"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagescv.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! cellimagesar

        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1

        cell.myImages.image = UIImage(named: imagescv [indexPath.row])
        cell.myImages.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 182, height: 290)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a UIButton press to work in a UICollectionViewCell in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750236/how-do-i-get-a-uibutton-press-to-work-in-a-uicollectionviewcell-in-swift)

Comment: "i don't want all buttons to do the same actions" What kind action you want to change on buttons? @Faisal

Comment: @Faisal I guess in that case you need to provide tag value to every button, and perform different action on different buttons.

Comment: Use tag value as indexpath.row of every button and add target for ever button when to initilize cell

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ i have 20 buttons and if you know how to make all of them as actions to do what i want only i need to know how to add buttons

Comment: Using `.tag` can become very problematic. Another solution is to use a Protocol / Delegate model. Or, use a "call back" closure. Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44371262/6257435

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the `tag` and `action` to the button inside the `collectionviewcell`.
Assign `indexPath.item` as button tag is the best approach to identify the particular button from the number of cells.
All you need to do within `cellForItemAt` delegate method.

```
cell.btnCounter.tag = indexPath.item
cell.btnCounter.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And now you just need to handle the event as below

```
func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Here sender.tag will give you the tapped Button index from the cell
        //You can identify the button from the tag  
    }
```

Comment: ok but where i can add the button action , can you give me a ex if you can

Comment: i use it like this `@objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if(sender.tag == 0) {
            print("ok")
        }
        else if(sender.tag == 1) {
            print("no")
        }
    }` it's good ?